# Buscar numero disponible en un campo auto increment con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito saber si hay alguna manera en PHP de buscar un **id** de una tabla con *autoincrement* pero que obviamente no haya sido utilizado antes.

Por ejemplo, la tabla que tengo es así:

```
id: 1024,
nombre: bla bla bla

id: 1026,
nombre: ta ta ta
```

Lo que necesitaría es que cuando inserte un nuevo usuario el script busque y vea que el id 1025 esta disponible y lo use. También si es posible que arranque a buscar desde cierto numero, por ejemplo 1000.

¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar esto con PHP?

Comment: Esto suena a *normalización* más que otra cosa. No es factible dedicarse a normalizar constantemente, mediante código. Si esas columnas aún no están relacionadas con nadie, recrea la tabla poniendo esa columna como auto_increment y para evitar saltos, controla antes de las inserciones, porque cuando un campo es auto_increment, si hay una inserción fallida, el campo aumenta en `1`, quedando ese valor sin datos, como puede que haya ocurrido en tu contexto.

Comment: Entiendo, el problema es que esta tabla ya tiene datos cargados y no es factible recrear la tabla. Mi pregunta era para saber si es posible hacer eso con PHP, y si es así, como sería lo mas recomendable.

Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Yo verificaría cuáles son los IDs disponibles, crearía una tabla con ellos y los iría usando en las nuevas inserciones y cuando estén todos usados, controlaría que los registros no existen antes de insertarlos, así como todos los eventuales errores que intentarían una inserción fallida. A mi juicio esto debería quedarse en el terreno de la *normalización*, no incorporado a la lógica de ningún programa, porque esto no es otra cosa que un error de diseño de las tablas o del código que gestiona las inserciones. Lo que querrías hacer aquí es corregir un error en el lugar equivocado (php).